# Creating A Multiline StackPanel

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm trying to create a stackpanel in WinRT that will wrap to the next line when needed.  I've tried WrapGrid and VariableSizeWrapGrid but seem to be having issues with the item size and layout.

My aim is to have a list of names separated by a "," that when I click on the name I can navigate to a new page with the Item passed as the navigation argument.

I    Don't Want The Items
To Line   Up    Like This

Which happens if I use a grid.  Instead I want something like

Name 1, Name Two, Name Three
Name Four, Name Five, Name Six

And clicking on a name fires an event. Each "Name" is a separate item in a collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought is that that doesn't sound very metro-esk. That being said, [this](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT) library has what you want.

> WrapPanel - WrapPanel ported from Silverlight. Allows variable sized
>   controls and wraps to a new line when needed.

There is a post about where it came from plus a sample app located [here](http://www.michielpost.nl/PostDetail_75.aspx).

If this isn't quite what you need you should be able to modify it to what you want fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I needed. As for it not being metro-esk.... I really only want <a href=> in html speak. HTML can be used in Metro Apps but I'm using XAML. It's basically just a list of names, you click the name if you wish and it filters an item set based on that name. I couldn't really think of a better way to do it but I'm always open to suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of anything better either.  :-P